# How do I fix the incorrect index in the chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

Here is a table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKR8E.png)
I have performed the following:

```
bat_bowl = table[['Team','Ba','Bo']]
bat_bowl.set_index('Team')

ax = bat_bowl.plot.bar(rot=25)
plt.title('Comparison of Batting and Bowling by Teams')
plt.xlabel('Teams')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBGGv.png)
Here is the problem I'm facing: Although 'Team' is the index, in the chart, numbers are appearing in the x-axis. Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance!

I was expecting the name of the teams to appear in the x-axis

Comment: Please don’t use pictures for data and show also your import for a minimal working example, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell Pandas to use the `"Team"` data as the x-data by passing the `x` argument the column name.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import string

N = 10
data = {"Team":list(string.ascii_lowercase[:N]),
        "Ba":np.random.random(N), 
        "Bo":np.random.random(N)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index("Team")

df.plot.bar(x="Team")
plt.show()
```

[image]